# Advanced Ramda Array Transformation

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming, ramda.js

**TLTR:** Look at the javascript snippet.

I have an array of items.

I want to map items and change their structure.

I need to keep some properties and I also need to set a new property. However, the new property value is going to be based on the item that I am currently mapping.

```js
// change title to whatever shape you desire
const customTitleTransformation = title => title

const arrayOfItems = [
  {
    id: 'some id 1',
    isSelected: true,
    title: 'some title 1',
    text: 'some text',
    description: 'some description'
  },
  {
    id: 'some id 2',
    isSelected: false,
    title: 'some title 2',
    text: 'some text',
    description: 'some description'
  },
]

// I need array of items like:
// {
//   id,
//   isSelected,
//   cells: [
//     customTitleTransformation(title),
//     text
//   ]
// }

// REGULAR JAVASCRIPT WAY  
const normalizedItems = arrayOfItems.map(item => ({
  id: item.id,
  isSelected: item.isSelected,
  cells: [
    customTitleTransformation(item.title),
    item.text,
  ]
}))

console.log('first result ', normalizedItems)

// USING RAMDA  

const normalizedItemsRamda = R.map(
  R.compose(
    R.pick(['id', 'isSelected', 'cells']),
    R.set(R.lensProp('cells'), ['how do I set the array?'])
  )
)(arrayOfItems)

console.log('ramda result ', normalizedItemsRamda)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be a case for `applySpec`.

The `mapObject` function defines the shape of the new object. That transformation is then applied to `arrayOfItems`.

Whether this feels more readable is entirely left to your appreciation of course:

```js
// change title to whatever shape you desire
const customTitleTransformation = title => title

const arrayOfItems = [{
    id: 'some id 1',
    isSelected: true,
    title: 'some title 1',
    text: 'some text',
    description: 'some description'
  },
  {
    id: 'some id 2',
    isSelected: false,
    title: 'some title 2',
    text: 'some text',
    description: 'some description'
  },
]

const mapObject = R.applySpec({
  id: R.prop('id'),
  isSelected: R.prop('isSelected'),
  cells: R.juxt([
    R.o(customTitleTransformation, R.prop('title')),
    R.prop('text')
  ])
});

const normalizedItemsRamda = R.map(mapObject, arrayOfItems)

console.log('ramda result ', normalizedItemsRamda)
console.log('\n\nOriginal Items Unchanged:')
console.log(arrayOfItems);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is beautiful. :) I like your solution even more than pure javascript.

Comment: Just one question where did you find `R.o`?

Comment: [`R.o`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#o) is just a simplified version of `compose`, taking exactly two unary functions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert with Ramda or FP by any stretch of the imagination, but it seems like the easiest way would be to pass a normal function into your `R.compose` that adds the cells property on to each object before `pick`ing the properties you want.

Let me know if this works for you, or if this is an anti-pattern and you are strictly looking for Ramda built-ins.

```js
// change title to whatever shape you desire
const customTitleTransformation = title => title

const arrayOfItems = [
  {
    id: 'some id 1',
    isSelected: true,
    title: 'some title 1',
    text: 'some text',
    description: 'some description'
  },
  {
    id: 'some id 2',
    isSelected: false,
    title: 'some title 2',
    text: 'some text',
    description: 'some description'
  },
]

// USING RAMDA  

const normalizedItemsRamda = R.map(
  R.compose(
    R.pick(['id', 'isSelected', 'cells']),
    // shallow copy, add cells property, return new updated object
    item => R.assoc('cells', [customTitleTransformation(item.title), item.text], item)
  )
)(arrayOfItems)

console.log('ramda result ', normalizedItemsRamda)
console.log('\n\nOriginal Items Unchanged:')
console.log(arrayOfItems);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice I just noticed that you change the `item.cells = ...` :)

Comment: @Michal Yeah, my first version modified the original list of items, the updated solution will leave them untouched, meaning no side-effects.

Comment: `item => R.assoc('cells', [customTitleTransformation(item.title), item.text], item)`? :)

Comment: @Michal Yes! that looks perfect, I will update my solution

Comment: Although I feel like no ramda solution is better. :D

Comment: @Michal I can't disagree with you there, it's certainly more explicit and unambiguous to the reader.